# Input field validation for two numbers

Tags: html, angularjs

I seem to be stuck with a validation issue for 2 numbers which I am passing in the input field. I provide 2 numbers in the input, say num1 and num2. num2 must be greater than num1. If it is not, then I need to show an error message. This is what I have tried so far. I am not seeing the error message being shown consistently. Appreciate it if someone could point out what I might be missing.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fmvsaf0/37/)

```
<input name="num1" type="text" ng-model="num1" placeholder="num1">
<input name="num2" type="text" ng-model="num2" placeholder="num2">
<span ng-show="num1>num2">Num2 cannot be lesser than num1</span>
```

Comment: In the JSFiddle it does work. What is not working in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have can use several ways

The first one is to change the input type to number

```js
 var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
 app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-form="regForm">
      <input name="num1" type="number" ng-model="num1" placeholder="num1">
      <input name="num2" type="number" ng-model="num2" placeholder="num2">
      <span ng-show="num1>num2">Num2 cannot be lesser than num1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another is to use the input as text and associate a controller function to `ng-show` so that it compares the integer and not the string values

```js
 var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
 app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
    $scope.checkNum = function(){
      return parseInt($scope.num1) > parseInt($scope.num2) 
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-form="regForm">
      <input name="num1" type="text" ng-model="num1" placeholder="num1">
      <input name="num2" type="text" ng-model="num2" placeholder="num2">
      <span ng-show="checkNum()">Num2 cannot be lesser than num1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Fiddle seems to work, except maybe that the message is showing also when num2 is empty. Changing `type="text"` to `"type="number"` makes it behave more like you would expect.

Comment: how can you say that "Your Fiddle seems to work, except maybe that the message is showing also when num2 is empty. " the ng-show = "num1>num2" is comparing the string values and your description does not mean that. You mean totally different. Despite of this i cannot understand why people are giving up vote for this.

Comment: It does what it says: ng-show makes the text magically appear when num1 is larger than num2, saying: num2 may not be less than num1.

Comment: That is not magic my friend that is because the ng-show is considering as a string and not as a number. You can't say that magic. Be logical.

Answer (score 0):

Change the text box  `type="text"`  to `type="number"`

```
<input name="num1" type="number" ng-model="num1" placeholder="num1">
<input name="num2" type="number" ng-model="num2" placeholder="num2">
<span ng-show="num1 > num2">Num2 cannot be lesser than num1</span>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6fmvsaf0/39/)

Comment: You have posted the same answer of Remko, and edited his post as well. Do not understand what it makes sense to give same answer again, with some code.

Comment: Am trying to fix on jsfiddle on that time he answered. that's why I have give +1 for Remko answer

Comment: Have you read his description "Your Fiddle seems to work, except maybe that the message is showing also when num2 is empty. " . Please understand what it means. I know you may know Angular better than me but the description, from any point does not say that the code was comparing the string value and not an integer value. The line is misleading and you have up voted it.